# vuetify project with express.js backend run in mobile network but unable to do backend processes

Tags: node.js, express, vuetify.js

I have a project that I built using `vuetify` for frontend and `node` with `express.js` for backend, the project works perfectly in my computer,
and also works in my phone when I access it using the ip giving by vuetify which is http://192.168.1.2:8080/ but when i try to login, 
it seems like it does not get the backend server which is running on http://localhost:5000. 
It does not give error or success it just does nothing.
[this is vuetify cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0losB.png)

[this is node server.js running in port 5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC7ms.png)

[this is my login page in my computer which works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsQfv.png)

[this is my login page in my phone which does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehyv7.jpg)

Comment: Hey Robel,  the application works fine on your computer because Vuetify can point to backend localhost:5000 on your computer but not on your mobile device. Try using your IP instead : http://192.168.1.2:5000/ to point to your backend. This should work!

Comment: just like this .....  app.listen(5000, "192.168.1.2",  () => console.log("server running on port 5000")); ???

Comment: No, I mean the node server runs on localhost:5000 on your computer,  so when the  vuetify runs on your computer it correctly points to the system 5000 port, whereas when running on the mobile device there is no server running on your mobile , so you need to point it to your computer IP along with port , like whereever you're trying to hit the api , just use the 192.168.1.2:5000

Comment: thank you, i solve the problem by adding environment variable, i added "VUE_APP_s_address=http://192.168.1.2:5000" in my .env file in vuetify project with out quote, and in my back end server.js .....  app.listen(5000);